# Swift 3 / Alamofire 4: Fetching data with the ID on a TableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, alamofire

I am trying to fetch data using an ID on the ViewController. I have two viewcontrollers, when I press the Cell (from ViewController 1), it has an ID and goes to ViewController 2 and fetches all the records that are assigned to the ID. For example, on ViewController 1, I have a UITableView and there are 20 cells. Each cells have an ID assigned to it dynamically from the database. When I press the cell, assuming I pressed 9th cell and its ID is 99, then it goes to the ViewController 2 and fetches all the records whose Foreign Key has ID 99.

Please find my code Below for ViewController 2:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON


class CategoryViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, NSURLConnectionDelegate {

var tableData = Array<Category>()
var arrRes = [[String:AnyObject]]() //Array of dictionary
var category = [Category]()
var catTitle = ""
var id = ""



@IBOutlet weak var catTitleRec: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!




override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    catTitleRec.text = catTitle
    loadCategories()
}

func loadCategories(){

    let testhappyhour:Category = Category(tempName: "category.NAME", tempID: "category.id",  tempgbcount: "TOTAL")
    self.category.append(testhappyhour)

    let postID = "id="+id

    print("Response ID-is: \(postID)") // Able to get the ID here

    Alamofire.request("http://www.URL.com.au/database/results.php").responseJSON
        { response in switch response.result {
        case .success(let JSON):
            let response = JSON as! NSArray
            print("Response: \(response)")
            for item in response { // loop through data items
                let obj = item as! NSDictionary
                let happyhour = Category(tempName:obj["category.NAME"] as! String, tempID:obj["category.id"] as! String,  tempgbcount:obj["TOTAL"] as! String)
                self.category.append(happyhour)
                self.arrRes.append(obj as! [String : AnyObject]) // ADD THIS LINE
            }
            self.tableview.reloadData()

        case .failure(let error):
            print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
            }
    }
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    tableview.reloadData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //return myarray.count
    return arrRes.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "groupCell") as! GroupCellTableViewCell
    var dict = arrRes[indexPath.row]

    cell.nametextlabel.text = dict["category.NAME"] as? String
    cell.totaltextlabel?.text = dict["TOTAL"] as? String

    return cell
}



}
```

Thanks for your time and effort :)

Comment: what problem are you facing ? is it showing data on second viewController ? or not getting id on controller 1?

Comment: @iOSGeek , I am not able to fetch the data. I am able to see the ID associated to it on the ViewController 2. I want to see all the related data who has the ID , for eg; 99

Comment: what error response you are getting in log ? is it your api in alamofire is not even getting Hitted it just out at error like code response (-1)

Comment: @iOSGeek i am now able to see the data in the output box, however its crashing down

Comment: the error i m getting is Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
func loadCategories(id : String) {


    let userDic : [String : AnyObject] = ["id":id as AnyObject]

      Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in

        for (key, value) in userDic {
            multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
        }

    },to: "http://www.URL.com.au/database/results.php" , method: .post, headers: nil ,
      encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.response { [weak self] response in
                guard self != nil else {
                    return
                }
                debugPrint(response)

            }

            upload.responseJSON {  response in

                print(response)
                let responseJSON = response.result.value as! NSDictionary


                print(responseJSON)



            }

        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print("error:\(encodingError)")
        }


    })
```

Call This Function With Your Id In ViewDidLoad

```
loadCategories(id:id)
```

Comment: First Pass Id From didselect method viewcontroller 1 to Viewcontroller 2 And then in viewcontroller2 call this loadCategories(id:id) you get the result definitely

Comment: Hi Bhavik, I tried the code but its not fetching any records based on the ID.

Comment: I can see the ID that is passed from ViewController 1 to ViewController 2 in the output panel

Comment: But I guess its crashing

Answer (score 0):

Make One Swift File And Put This Code APi.swift

```
APi.swift

    import Foundation

    import Alamofire


    class APIClient {

    internal typealias CompletionBlock = (_ data:NSDictionary?,_ error:NSError?) -> Void

         fileprivate class func executePostAPICallWithMethod(_ method:String ,withParameters parameters:AnyObject?, callback:@escaping CompletionBlock) {

                let str = method


                Alamofire.request(str, method: .post, parameters: parameters as? [String : AnyObject], encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
                    switch response.result {
                    case .success(let JSON):
                        //                    print("Success with JSON: \(JSON)")
                        print("Request failed with error: \(response.response?.statusCode)")

                        let response = JSON as! NSDictionary

                        callback(response,nil)
                        break

                    case .failure(let error):
                        print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
                        callback(response.result.value as? NSMutableDictionary,error as NSError?)
                        break
                    }
                    }
                    .responseString { response in
                        print("Response String: \(response.result.value)")
                }

            }

          class func loadCategories(_ detail : [String : AnyObject],completion:@escaping CompletionBlock){

                let strMethod = String(format : "http://www.URL.com.au/database/results.php" )
                self.executePostAPICallWithMethod(strMethod, withParameters: detail as AnyObject?) { (data, error) -> Void in
                    completion(data,error)
                }
            }

    }
```

In ViewController 2 Call This Function In ViewDidLoad

```
func loadCategories(id : String)
{
 let userDic : [String : AnyObject] = ["id":id as AnyObject]

        APIClient.loadCategories(userDic,completion:{ (data, error)->Void in
            if((error) != nil) {

                if((data) != nil){


                } else {

                }
            } else {

                print(data as Any)



                //self.tableview.reloadData()
            }

        })

}
```

Comment: Let Me Know It's working Or not ?if Any query then let me know

Comment: Nope, it failed

Comment: got this error : Request failed with error: responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 2."

Comment: But it did work with your previous respond you posted

Comment: but it crashed :(

Comment: in the respond print or not?

Comment: put your new code how to populate the responce so i understand helping you.and in responce you get the array or json check first and then check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148006/discussion-between-bhavik-panchal-and-sarah-malik).

Comment: yea sure, Lets move to chat